# Existence of local equation on prime divisors and well definedness ( independent of affine open)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am new to algebraic geometry and I am trying to learn about divisors from Shaferavich's Basic algebraic geometry Chapter 3.

First, we need a definition and a theorem:

[image]

[image]

1. So if I am understanding the definition of local equations correctly, $\mathfrak{a}_{Y^{\prime}}=\left(f_1, \ldots, f_m\right)$ just means that the set of functions in $k[X']$ whose restriction to $Y'$ vanishes is generated by $f_1,......f_m)$ correct?
2. And theorem 2.10 is saying that if we have an irreducible subvariety of codimension 1, and the point $x$ is nonsingular, then we can find an affine open around the point such that the ideal is principal, or generated by one element correct?
3. Now for the part I have highlighted, I want to ask why we can find an affine open satisfying those conditions.
4. Perhaps, answering this related question would clarify the reason:
   If we have a affine open neighbourhood defined by 1 local equation, is it still defined by the same local equation if we shrink the affine neighbourhood (technically, this should be the local equation restricted to the smaller set) assuming of course it still intersects our prime divisor $C$?. The text seems to imply this is obvious when it proves the valuation of $f$ is independent of affine open, but I don't see why this is obvious. Because if we shrink our open set, the set of functions that can potentially vanish on the smaller set is larger, so why would the ideal still be generated by the same element?

Now for the proof that the valuation of $f$ is independent of affine open:
[image]

5. Again I don't see why it is obvious that "$\pi$ is a local equation for $C$ also in $V$, and obviously then $v_C^U(f)=v_C^V(f)$" as I mentioned above.

I hope these questions are not too basic. I am new to algebraic geometry and I find the theorems here very confusing.